# Excel SUMIFS on multiple conditions stuck

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with my `SUMIFS` in excel.

Basically I want to sum values on given conditions. This is the workbook:[Workbook available](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=FE479525195477F7!3477&ithint=file%2Cxlsx&app=Excel&authkey=!AG_gKA_8TBXmpXE)

The data in the workbook is very simple but the structure is the same.

**Question**:

How can I code a SUMIFS in excel if I need to sum on the conditions of Month and service? Example sum actual customers for service p A in month 201501?

I tried something like this: =SUMIFS(A3:I5="Service";B1:I1="Month";B2:I2="Actual Customers")

Please observe ";" is my local usage in excel
It did not work.

Comment: The SumProduct formula in cell C8 returns the correct result.  Sumifs cannot do what you need in this scenario. Sumifs can evaluate a one-column or a one-row range, not a two dimensional table. Sumproduct can. And it delivers the correct result.  What is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to prepare a new managerial report and I am trying to experiment a bit. My data is actually a bit more bulkier than in the workbook. Basically, I want to sum the total for a product when month and actual customers match. Something like SUM P a Service when column header is "total" and "actual customers". Is there a way of achieving this? SUMIFS does not look like to provide the solution for this.

Comment: Sumproduct does. what you describe. Use Sumproduct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for [`SUMIFS`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193011.aspx)

Instead of using a conditional like `A3:I5="Service`, Excel expects you to first list the range you want to apply the criteria to, and then what the criteria is. In addition you haven't listed the range you want to sum if all your criteria is fulfilled, this comes first in `SUMIFS`-formula, as you can see if you use the function helper (click `fx` next to the formula line):

[image]

Finally, it seems that not all your ranges are the same size, which I suspect will also create problems, I am not sure about this though. Checking against the documentation on the MSDN page for `SUMIFS`, Microsoft claims that the ranges *do not* need to be the same size:

> Each criteria_range does not have to be the same size and shape as sum_range. The actual cells that are added are determined by using the top, left cell in that criteria_range as the beginning cell, and then including cells that correspond in size and shape to sum_range.

However, as was pointed out in the comments, their support page for `SUMIFS` claims the opposite, and this is further confirmed by testing in Excel. In short, you should probably stick with having the criteria_ranges being the same size as the sum_range.

Comment: Ranges absolutely **do** need to be exactly the same size and shape in `SUMIFS` -otherwise you will get `#VALUE!` error - the part you have highlighted is not correct - I think the confusion is because **SUMIF** function (not `SUMIFS`) works like that, the actual sum range used is matched with the criteria range, e.g. `=SUMIF(A1:A10,"x",C3)` is valid - the actual sum_range used will be `C3:C12`

Comment: @barryhoudini Huh, that is odd - am I misunderstanding something on  the MSDN page, or is it actually mistaken? There's a link to it at the top of my answer. Testing in my Excel version (2013) does indeed confirm what you say.

Comment: I think that's wrong - see this link: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b - towards the bottom of that it says: "The Criteria_range argument must contain the same number of rows and columns as the Sum_range argument" - As I say, only `SUMIF` works as they describe, not `SUMIFS`

Comment: @barryhoudini Yeah, that was my impression as well. Heh, they should get round to correcting that page, then - the description at the top wasn't very good either, I felt.